# How do I use the following difference root (LDE) to extract a partial sum of the harmonic series below?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, harmonic-numbers

I asked WolframAlpha about some partial sum formula for the following divergent series:

$$\sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{H_x}{ax\pm1} = ??$$
Where $H_x$ is the $x$th harmonic number.
It informed me that it is indeed divergent, then spat out the following for the partial sum formula:

$$DifferenceRoot[\{y, n\}, Function \{(n + 1) (a n \pm 1) y(n) - (n + 1) (2 a n + a \pm 2) y(n + 1) + (n + 1) (a n + a \pm 1) y(n + 2) - 1 = 0, y (0) = 0, y (1) = 0\}](m + 1) \mp \frac{1}{1 \pm a}$$

What am I supposed to do with that? I checked the documentation, it's not entirely clear how you can use this without a Wolfram Notebook product license. What techniques should I even be thinking about here to solve this, something regarding linear differential equations?

Comment: @JohnOmielan  You're right, editing now.

Comment: You might want to remind us what $H_x$ means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Done!

Comment: What is your question? Do you want an exact formula for the partial sums of this series? or an approximation?

Comment: @GregMartin Edited title (the question) for clarity! If you can give a decent (minimal bounded error) closed form approximation, neat.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem because of the $\pm 1$. If it was just
$$\sum_{n=2}^p \frac {H_n}{an}=\frac{6 \left(H_p\right){}^2-6 \psi ^{(1)}(p+1)+\pi ^2-12}{12 a}$$ which is an upper or lower bound for your summation.

Assuming that $a$ is large, what you could do is to write
$$\sum_{n=2}^p \frac {H_n}{an\pm 1}\sim \sum_{n=2}^m \frac {H_n}{an\pm 1}+\sum_{n=m+1}^p \frac {H_n}{an}$$ Compute the first summation and the second one is
$$\sum_{n=m+1}^p \frac {H_n}{an}=\frac{\left(H_p\right){}^2-\left(H_m\right){}^2+\psi ^{(1)}(m+1)-\psi^{(1)}(p+1)}{2 a}$$

**Edit**

For the case of

$$S_k=\sum_{n=2}^p \frac {H_n}{n+k}$$ where $k$ is an integer, the formulae are quite simple

$$S_1=\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(H_{p+1}\right){}^2-H_{p+1}^{(2)}-1\right)$$
$$S_2=\frac{1}{6} \left(3 \left(H_{p+2}\right){}^2-3 H_{p+2}^{(2)}+\frac{6}{p+2}-8\right)$$
$$S_3=\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(H_{p+3}\right){}^2+\frac{1}{p+2}+\frac{3}{p+3}+\psi^{(1)}(p+4)-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-4\right)$$

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing about $a$ besides it being a real number, can be assumed.

Comment: @user3108815. Then the problem starts to be still more difficult.

Comment: The question now is how are they related, and of course how are we supposed to use the difference root? Apparently it's a recurrence relation that can help us???

Comment: Bravo! What happens when k is no longer an integer?
Also, I've almost solved the general case of: $\sum_{n=2}^p \frac{H_n}{an^2-1}$ for $a \in \Bbb R\ s.t. \lvert a \rvert>1$. I'm very excited.

Comment: @user3108815. If $k$ is not an integer, there is a solution but it involves recurrence equations   https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BHarmonicNumber%5Bn%5D%2F%28n%2BPi%29%2C%7Bn%2C2%2Cp%7D%5D

Comment: It turns out the entire problem is related to: $\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} \frac{H(p+\frac{1}{\sqrt a})}{p+3}$. Furthermore, the problem was _not_ the $+1$, it's actually the fact that $\frac{1}{\sqrt a} \notin \Bbb N$, at least not necessarily!

Comment: Hello @Claude, I have a picture which may aid in the answer, I was hoping you'd be able to see it but I think we need to move to chat for that. Instead, here is a link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%5B+polygamma%280%2C+n+%2B+3%29%5D%2F%28n%2B1%2Fa%29+from+n+%3D+2+to+m

What is being said here?